# Value lacks methods that variable has despite being same type

Tags: scala

Consider the following two declarations:

```
var x: Int = 0
val y: Int = 0
```

`x` is a **variable** whereas `y` is a **value**, both of the **same type**: **`Int`**.

I can use `+=` on `x`:

```
x += 1
x.+=(1)
```

However, if I try to use `+=` on `y`, I get a compile-time error — "Not Found Error" (`E008`) — with the description:

> `+=` is not a member of `Int`

I understand that `y` is immutable because it's a value, and this behavior is desirable.

What mechanism does Scala use to provide `x` and `y` with different methods taking into account that they are both of type `Int`?

Comment: If there is no `def +=` on your type `X` (in `scala.Int` there isn't) Scala tries to rewrite code into `x1 = x1.+(x2)`. This requires only existence of `+` operator with matching type AND availability of `=` assignment. `var` has it available, `val` doesn't. You can see it in user defined types in scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mIj1tJgmQ1Ocp5vCeRA58g

Comment: Thank you @MateuszKubuszok if you could make your comment into an answer, I would accept it.